# Why can I create a foreign key constraint to a non-existent table?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I was playing around with foreign key constraints and realized that I can add a constraint to a non-existent table. I can also insert records, no problem.

```
mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table t(id int, FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES x(id));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into t values (1);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
```

I am wondering if I don't quite understand foreign key constraints.

Comment: The table creation fails on SQL Fiddle:  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f75a.

Comment: You can do lots of things with non-existent tables in mysql, eg create views on them.

Comment: @Bohemian Why would DB engines allow that?

Comment: Generally speaking, mysql is lax. But, it's actually very handy. You can for example drop/recreate a table that a view depends on without first dropping the view then recreating it later. If there are many view, it can save a *lot* of work. Other databases require strict dependencies, but that just leads to more work. I used to think it was "bad", and that strictness was good. Now I think it saves time. If your build server exercises the database, dependency problems will be detected then, so it does cause any *actual* problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the default storage is set to MyIsam, not InnoDb, and the table is created as MyIsam, not Innodb.
Foreign keys are only supported by Innodb tables.
For MyIsam tables, foreign key constraints are not supported, and while creating the table with `create table` command, a foreign key specification is parsed, but it is ignored.
Try to set `innodb` as a default engine using `SET storage_engine=innodb;`, or create a table using explicitely Innodb like this:

```
create table t(id int, FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES x(id)) engine=innodb;
```

Comment: Btw: you can also make InnoDB ignore foreign key definitions: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d757/1